# What should moderators do when someone is "astroturfing" the site?

Tags: discussion

Just now I was notified by the system of a user posting the same answer to multiple questions (four at last count).  The answer pointed to the user's github repository and a video that I believe they made.

The answers, while somewhat relevant to the question asked, did not attempt to answer the individual questions directly.

My response has been to delete all of the copied answers and notify the user by private message that they've been doing something counter-productive (the first time I've ever had to do that as a mod!).

Was this the right response?

Can you suggest better / different responses?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a perfectly valid solution! I will keep an eye on that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fully agree with your response. Should the behavior happen again, an action on the author's account could be deserved.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way you handled it is perfectly reasonable--especially since the behavior was from an unregistered user. Given that all the answers were strict copy-paste, and had no real content besides links, we have yet to see any proof that this wasn't a bot. [UPDATE: It wasn't.]

We had one other situation like this early on, but it was from a registered user, and the answers were mostly screenshots of software. In that case, we just encouraged the user to actually answer the questions (in addition to linking).

Comment: Thanks for the background!  It looks like they are not a bot; I've just seen another answer from them with the same links, but much more detailed information addressing the question, too.